# connect remotly to mysql server

Tags: php, mysql

I want to connect to mysql server remotly .in the local host there is no problem. I check `my.conf` file but `bind-address` line and `skip-networking` no exist in the `my.conf` .this is my `my.conf` :

```
[mysqld]
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql

symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

when connect to mysql server from another server this error message displayed :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysite.com' (13)
```

I add this line to my.conf :

```
bind-address= 0.0.0.0
```

and then restart mysql server but problem still exist .also I turn off firewall with iptables.
I think the problem is about port.default port is 3306. I try to change default port to 8806 but after change port mysql server does not start .
this problem take my time for several day. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try to add you IP as bind-address, not 0.0.0.0. Port must be fine.

Comment: Did you specify a correct IP for `bind-address`? Have you GRANT'ed your sql user to connect remotely?

Comment: @umka I don't think, GRANT is a problem here: if it was, the message would have been "Access denied", not "Can't connect".

Comment: @ user4035 if i add ip address to bind-address mysql server is available only for that ip address .but i want to mysql server available for several ip arrdess.

Comment: @umka this error is about mysql server is not reachable .if i remove bind-address mysql server must reachable from all ip address

Comment: I've read the docs, actually `0.0.0.0` makes it accessible by any server IP. Ok. If your mysql server doesn't start, check the error log for the reason. If it starts successfully, but you can't connect, run `netstat` (or `sockstat`) command to see, if it listens on corresponding ports and IPs.